# tab bar slide animation swift 4

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, swift4, uitabbar

I want to add animation to the tab swipe. How can it be done in swift 4 without using any library?

I have two tabs I swipe in the screen right or left its change the tab bar.

How would I make it so it looks like it is sliding to the right or left tab bar rather than just instantly changing the tab-bar.

Also, I have defined the gesture separately in FirstViewController & SecondViewController. Is there a way to define it at one place and call it. #newToSwift

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

    }

    @objc func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        print(sender.direction);
        if sender.direction == .left {
            if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! < 2 { // set your total tabs here
                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex += 1
            }
        } else if sender.direction == .right {
            if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! > 0 {
                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex -= 1
            }
        }
    }


}
```

This is second ViewController.

//  SecondViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    @objc func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        print(sender.direction);
        if sender.direction == .left {
            if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! < 2 { // set your total tabs here
                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex += 1
            }
        } else if sender.direction == .right {
            if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! > 0 {
                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex -= 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could create your own `UITabBarController` subclass and add the gesture recognizers to its view and take it from there. Should work the same as the code you shared.

Comment: can you give an example of implementing the animation ? @donnywals